# Pass Variable to Jquery file from a html page

Tags: jquery, html

I have 1 Jquery and 2 html file. I created a html page to have select option like this.

```
<p class="style1">
        Select your category :
        <select id="selection" name="D1">
            <option value ="football" selected =selected>Football Team</option>
            <option value ="Movie">Movie</option>
        </select></p>

    <p class="style1">
        </p>
```

I wanted get the value of the from the option and pass into a Jquery to process and do something.

Next I want to show the result into another html page. Is it possible?

Because I dunno how can I pass in the variables to my Jquery file and how can I do a function so that I can direct to another page after I have selected my option. Should I direct to my jquery file(since I need to pass my variables to my jquery first) or the result html?

Sorry for asking noob question. Because I'm a noob. :(

**UPDATE:**

```
$.each(json.data, function(i,v){
 pts.push([v.topic, v.audience.length]);
});

Highcharts.getOptions().colors = $.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
    return {
        radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
        stops: [
            [0, color],
            [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
    ]
    };
});

    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Facebook like'
            },
            tooltip:{
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                percentageDecimals: 0
                }


            ,
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events:{
                            click: function (event){
                                //var personame =" ";
                                var id ="10150616324193820";
                                for (var i = 0; i < jsonFB.user1.length; i++) {
                                    for (var k = 0; k < json.data.length; k++) {
                                        for (var j = 0; j < json.data[k].audience.length; j++) {


                                       if (jsonFB.user1[i].id = json.data[k].audience[j].userid) {
                                            var personname = jsonFB.user1[i].name;

                                            var id = jsonFB.user1[i].id;



                                            }

                                       else {

                                           alert("Error!");

                                             }

                                             }


                                            }

                                    alert("Person who like "+this.name +" are "+ personname);
                                    var ans = confirm("Do you want to view this person profile?");
                                    if (ans)
                                      window.location="http://www.facebook.com/people/@/"+id;


                            }
                        }
                        }
                    },
                    showInLegend: true ,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',

                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.round(this.percentage) +'%';
                        }

                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Likes',
                data: pts

            }]
        });
    });


});
```

I wanna get the "selection" value to do an if else statement but for now I still dunno how to get it yet.

Comment: Use jQuery to process the option, and server-side code to POST to another page where you can GET that variable. Or you could simply use AJAX.

Comment: Yes use `form` to send the value. If you are asking to use it with ajax then also you need to do it with `form` elem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's with this you can bind `onchange` for a `select` to some method

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#selection").change(function(){

       console.log($(this).val()); //this will return the selected value

     });

});
```

Comment: How this will get process on other page?

Comment: Do you want this value to be printed on another page? Be specific.

Comment: post your `jquery` what you have?

Comment: But how should I code so that when I select then it will direct me to the result page?

Comment: Don need :)
I need that value to do an if else statement.